# DataContractJsonSerializer treats some values incorrectly

Tags: c#, json, wcf, datacontractjsonserializer

I faced with strange problem .Bellow you can see my test code

```
[DataContract]
public class Test
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{ \"Name\" :   Isometext  }"));
    var s = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Test));
    var r = (Test)s.ReadObject(ms);
    Console.WriteLine(r.Name);
}
```

> name = Isometext  -  OK
>
> name = Tsometext   -Exception
>
> name = Nsometext -   OK
>
> name = sometext -    Exception
>
> name = nsometext -   Exception

Why DataContractJsonSerializer treats values which starts with capital **I** and **N** as correct values? Is it bug?

Comment: seems like an invalid json string. did you try to wrap your **sometext** string in double quote like `"{ \"Name\" :   \"sometext\"  }"`

Comment: Is it mandatory to use the DataContractJsonSerializer? I know this question is not related to the question that you have asked. But I am still curious on why you are using the DataContractJsonSerializer when Newtonsoft.Json can provide you better performance.

Comment: works only with `UTF8`.

Comment: @Krishna Kumar N,this serializator is used in wcf and change it to Newtonsoft.Json is not trivial.But yes,I need change it

Answer (score 1):

wow, digging it up further led me [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Runtime/Serialization/Json/XmlJsonReader.cs,43a6542198588ac6)

As you have not wrapped **Isometext** with double quotes, *DataContractJsonSerializer* is treating that as a Number format, where it seems to consider

> N for NaN

and

> I for Infinity

And, NewtonSoft.JSON seems to handle it better than DataContractJsonSerializer. See http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonNetVsDotNetSerializers.htm

Comment: you are right,but this is incorrect json format if we pass Nsometext?

Comment: yes, that's incorrect. DataContractJsonSerializer seems to be considering Nsometext as NaN

Answer (score -1):

No idea why it's behaving differently for capitals and non-capitals, but to fix it you need to encase your string value in "", such as \"isometext\".

Comment: This is not escape.You just turned this value to string literal

Comment: You can't just make up your own interpretation of the json spec and expect it to work though. Strings in json need to be encased in quotes.

From the json spec "A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes. A character is represented as a single character string. A string is very much like a C or Java string."

Comment: Yea,and we didn't encased it in quotes,it should throw exception,but for some values(see examples in my question),exception isn't thrown.This is a question

Comment: I'm assuming it's *trying* to handle your uppercase value as a string to be tolerant to data coming in, but using some form of camel case resolution internally that is then trying to see it as a property name so throwing an error.

Comment: Notice,If capital letter is not I or N,for example name = Tssss,it will throw exception.

Comment: it's really curious to find out why using "I" and "N" works but, why not simply resolve this issue using quotation marks, since "Name" is a string, as @SimonHardy suggested? If the Name has a middle name, you will need to enclose with quotation marks, or your json will be wrong due to the space. It's a strange behavior of DataContractJsonSerializer, but your string is missing the quotation marks anyway.

Comment: Name is only for example.The real case,if someone pass Null without quotation marks.I want exception,but it is treated as "Null" string